# Geocoding with Google API c#

Tags: c#, api, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

I need to get coordinates from an address, here is function for this:

```
public static string getCoordonneesAdresse(string adresse)
    {
        var requestUri = string.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={0}&sensor=false", Uri.EscapeDataString(adresse));

        var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

        var result = xdoc.Element("GeocodeResponse").Element("result");
        var locationElement = result.Element("geometry").Element("location");
        var lat = locationElement.Element("lat");
        var lng = locationElement.Element("lng");
        string coord = lat.ToString() + lng.ToString();
        return coord;
    }
```

It is working but sometimes it complains at `over_query_limit`. Is there a way to fix that? Maybe I can do the request based on user IP.

I need your help!

Thanks you

Comment: problem solved by adding a key from google documentation

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/overview